# Why won't self.navigationController pushViewController work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a

> UIViewController-> UINavigationBar + UITableView

Just a bit more explanation

I made it through UIBuilder..

**1:** Created a New `UIViewController` with XIB-file
**2:** Using `UIBuiler` i put a `UINavigationController`
**3:** Then i put `UITableView` underneath the `navigationBar`
 so it gave me..

> A: UIViewController-> UINavigationBar + UITableView

Now i am loading the data in UITableView from a Webservice which is working fine.

I again made a xib with sam config which is

> B: UIViewController-> UINavigationBar + UITableView

So now when i try to push view B on view A using below code...it wont at all work...

```
SelectSiteViewController *siteViewController = [[SelectSiteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectSiteViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:siteViewController animated:YES];
```

When i checked the `UINavigationController *nav = self.navigation`

nav is 0x0 that is i assume NIL.

Can anybody tell me whats wrong in here.. why is it nil...and how can i make it work..

Thanks a Lot....I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UIBuilder verify that UINavigationController is referenced by the File's owner.

Comment: When you drop a UINavigationBar from UIBuilder library is it a UINavigationController? It is a UINavigationBar.

Comment: Its just the bar that appears in the view.  You need to either drag and drop UINavigationController in UIBuilder and hook it up to the File's owner's navigation controller.  Or you could create in the code.

Comment: Hey can i send you the code ....I tried but couldn't figure out...I would really appreciate any help...Thanks Man

Comment: I would highly recommend you read "Head First Iphone Development". It is really well written and has examples of exactly what you are trying to do.  It will save you countless hours and help you get productive fast.

Answer (score 2):

Got it.

I changed the Architecture a little bit.

I made a New UIViewController class with its xib. And coded new UINavigationController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationController *navigationController
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];   


switch (whichViewController) {
    case 1:
        viewController = [[xxxx alloc] init];           
        break;
    case 2:
        viewController = [[xxx1 alloc] init];           
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
[viewController release];
```

}

And pushing the view in the Switch Statement....

I hope this makes sense ......

Thanks jamihash

Answer (score 1):

So you are adding the tableview to the navigation controller right? This is how:

```
tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

[navigationController pushViewController:tableView animated:NO];
```

The tableview gets added as the rootview to the navigation controller. And then on selecting a row if you wish to push another viewcontroller use the

```
self.navigationController pushViewController: newViewController animated:YES];
```

inside the didSelectRowAtIndex method.

NOTE: its UITableViewController *tableView and UINavigationController *navigationController by declaration. So code accordingly for your table.

Comment: No no...

I created a new file that is UIViewController with XIB option Selected. For ex: 

@interface ClasssName : UIViewController <some delegates>{

}

So it is a Subclass of UIViewController

Now i opened the xib file and drop UINavigationBar
Then i drop UITableView onto the xib file which is UIViewController

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

why UIViewController-> UINavigationBar + UITableView ?

I suggest you another approach 
->UITableViewController A -> Embedded with a Navigation Controller, then after populate tableview you can pass data to 
->UITableViewController B by
[[self storyboard]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerB"];

then, in storyboard, drop a tableView B and in Identity->storyboard Id put some id.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
NSString *sUrl= @"<#string#>";
if (indexPath.row == 0) sUrl= @"http://www.apple.com/";
if (indexPath.row == 1) sUrl= @"http://www.google.com/";
if (indexPath.row == 2) sUrl= @"http://www.times.uk/";

NSMutableArray *selectedObject = [arrayOpenMale objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@ is the selected object.",selectedObject);

SeriesAdetailVC *dvc = [[self  storyboard]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];
dvc.strings7 = [NSURL URLWithString:sUrl];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];

}
```

hope help