# UIViewController - addSubview working but not presentModalViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` and I present an `GTLMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` (google authentication), which is a view controller as well. I present that using "presentModalViewController." Then, after authentication succeeds, the `GTLMOAuth2ViewController` dismisses itself. Next, I attempt to present another `UIViewController`, at which point if I say:

```
[self presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

it does not work, and no view controller shows. However, if I put:

```
[self.view addSubview:anotherViewController.view];
```

it does work, except that the view seems to be too low on the screen.

Why can I not use `presentModalViewController`?

Comment: hope it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221988/self-navigationcontroller-pushviewcontroller-wont-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on the timing you call presentModalViewController. My recent experience in the similar situation is that you cannot call presentModalViewController before viewDidAppear is called. If you do, nothing will happen. But you can call addSubview in loadView or viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and works perfectly fine.

I cannot answer "why" it is like this, but this is my observation. Hope this helps!